# can't find overloaded method from inherited class template

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, class-template

This is the first time I am using class templates so please don't be to harsh if I made a simply mistake.

I have a class template `class A<class T>`. It has a method `init()` that is pure virtual and therefore will be implemented separately in every derived class. What all these possible derived classes will have in common is an `init(T* i_x)` which basically does some general stuff and then calls the `init()`. Because this will be the same for every derived class I want to define it in the base class template already. But somehow my compiler doesn't find the right function.

If I try to use the `init(T* i_x)` on an object of a derived class `A_der` I get the error:

> no matching function for call to 'A_der::init(B_der*)

The classes used for the template parameter `T` will all be derived from another `class B`. Therefore the error message involves the `class B_der` which is derived from `class B`.

I boiled the problem down to a small example, which should involve everything that is important for the problem. If I try to compile this example in Visual Studio (normally I work in STM32CubeIDE) I get the following error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error C2660   **'A_der::init': function does not take 1
> arguments**   template_class-overload_inherited_method    [...]\main.cpp  8

So somehow the only function the compiler finds at this point is `init()` but not the base class template method `init(T* )`.

Can somebody please tell me why it is like that and what can I do to get the behaviour I want (without implementing a similar `init(T* )` in every derived class of A?

Here is my example code:

**base class template A - declaration - A.hpp**

```
template<class T>
class A
{
protected:
    T* m_x;

public:
    virtual void connect(T* i_x) final;

    virtual void init() = 0;

    virtual void init(T* i_x) final;
};
```

**base class template A - implementation - A.cpp**

```
#include "A.hpp"

template<class T>
void A<T>::connect(T* i_x)
{
    //some checks
    m_x = i_x; //connects object of B to A
}

template<class T>
void A<T>::init(T* i_x)
{
    connect(i_x);
    init();
}
```

**derived class A_der**

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B_der.hpp"

#pragma once
class A_der : public A<B_der>
{
    void init() override;
};

void A_der::init()
{
    //Initialization which needs a B_der connected already
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "B_der.hpp"
#include "A_der.hpp"

int main(void)
{
    B_der testB;
    A_der testA;
    testA.init(&testB);

    return 0;
}
```

For the sake of completeness:

```
class B
{

};

class B_der : public B
{

};
```

---

EDIT - Solved

Thanks a lot for the fast replies.
The combination of the comments from @BoP and @Jarod42 solved the problem.
I had to unhide the method with `using A<B_der>::init` (actually renaming might be the more elegant way) and move the implementation of `A` into `A.hpp`.

I will offer the updated example which builds successfully with Visual Studio 2019 for me here:

**base class A**

```
template<class T>
class A
{
protected:
    T* m_x;

public:
    virtual void connect(T* i_x) final;

    virtual void init() = 0;

    virtual void init(T* i_x) final;
};


template<class T>
void A<T>::connect(T* i_x)
{
    //some checks
    m_x = i_x; //connects object of B to A
}

template<class T>
void A<T>::init(T* i_x)
{
    connect(i_x);
    init();
}
```

**derivad class A_der**

A_der.hpp

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B_der.hpp"

class A_der : public A<B_der>
{
public:
    void init() override;

    using A<B_der>::init;
};
```

A_der.cpp

```
#include "A_der.hpp"

void A_der::init()
{
    //Initialization which needs a B_der connected already
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "B_der.hpp"
#include "A_der.hpp"

int main(void)
{
    B_der testB;
    A_der testA;
    testA.init(&testB);

    return 0;
}
```

for completeness

B.hpp

```
class B
{
};
```

B_der.hpp

```
#include "B.hpp"

class B_der : public B
{
};
```

I also forgot to make the methods of `A_der` public in the earlier example, this is corrected here. And I removed the `#pragma once`s in this example.

Comment: Unrelated: Why do you have a return statement `return true;` inside the function `void A<T>::connect`. This function's return type is `void` so you should not have `return true;` inside it.

Comment: `using A<B_der>::init` should unhide the method.

Comment: *"base class template A - implementation - A.cpp"*. See [why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: `virtual void connect(T* i_x) final;`. What is the purpose of declaring the base method both `virtual` and `final`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A_der : public A<B_der>
{
    void init() override;
};
```

When you declare a function `init` in the derived class, it hides all things named `init` from the base class. This is just like when declaring something in an inner scope - it hides things with the same name from outer scopes.

There are ways to import the hidden names, but an easy solution would be to just chose a different name, like `init_base`. Or, probably better, pass a parameter to the class constructor.